# How to open a flutter application when clicked on certain type of file in Android?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm looking for ways through which I can open my flutter app whenever a user clicks on a certain type of file(for example pdf).

Like when we click on a pdf file we are generally presented with applications(like google pdf viewer, office, etc) that have capabilities of opening that file. So, I want to know how I can do the same thing for my flutter app. I want my app to open and also receive the path of the file in this process.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Check out this documentation from Android: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters

Comment: Thanks, that's a really helpful article.
I also found an answer that worked fine for me. Here's the link to it [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59364498/how-to-open-audio-file-from-file-manager-using-flutter-app).